# Using Wi-Fi sensing, could I distinguish directions of moving objects based on time of flights?

Tags: ieee-802.11

I would like to distinguish the directions of a moving object using Wi-Fi sensing, in an arrangement like this diagram:

[image]

In my assumption, 1) set up two scanner: A (0, 0, 5) and B (3, 3, 2)
2) there are four moving objects (1, 2, 3, 4).

When the moving objects emit their probe requests, the scanner A and B detect the request. The arrival time can change to distance between the scanners and objects. The combinations of the scanner A and B can distinguish the directions (for example, object 1 comes from right to left).

Is it possible? can you share some keywords or researches related to this work? I will conduct some experiments but I would like to listen feedback from the experts like you as I'm a beginner in this field.

Comment: I don't think this Stack Exchange is the right place for such a question, but I'm not sure where to point you.

Comment: I think this is more on-topic for [electronics.se].

Comment: There appear to be quite a few questions of this kind on Stack Overflow, tagged `indoor positioning systems`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is certainly *possible*, on its scientific basis -- it's the fundamental principle of GPS -- but it's difficult to achieve in *practice* for a number of reasons.

(You'll need at least N+1 sensors, though, to position in N dimensions, unless there are constraints such as the objects are trains on known tracks.  Your diagram has only two sensors and you'd need three to position in two dimensions or four for three dimensions.)

**Localisation by transmission time**

- Speed of radio is 30 ns/metre
- The access points need to have very well synchronised clocks
- The access points need to have high-precision timestamping on the reception times of the frames
- The resolution of the position needs to be suitable for the resolutions of the timing
- If it's indoor, there are a lot of indirect paths to worry about
- If you only need direction of motion, not position, sometimes shortcuts are available

If you've got the resolution and the timestamping, it's an interesting project.  Be warned it's not at all easy and it's unlikely you'll want to do it for production use.  The mathematics is all about getting rid of noise in the data and minimising error.

**Localisation by signal strength**

This is much more practical with typical access points, especially if you only actually want direction.

- All access points maintain signal strength indicators
- The temporal resolution is poor however
- Depending on the application, zoning might be enough and can be easy
- It all comes down to the signal processing to smooth the rather erratic signal strengths

This is certainly done with wifi in many organisations, if only to say User 99 is in Building 7.  I've never seen it done with any direction indication, however.

Signal strength localisation is commonly used by cellular operators for police purposes etc.  I understand it's industrial quality nowadays, and I'd expect good algorithms to be relatively easy to find.  As with localisation by timing, the mathematics is all about minimising errors.

**Pointers**

I'd recommend you look at:

- Hewlett-Packard Application Note 1272 *GPS and Precision Timing Applications*, 1996.  This is an excellent 28-page overview of how GPS works, the algorithms, and the equations needed.  Although it's about GPS rather than wifi, the principles are identifical.  You'll find copies online easily, but they move around.
- A book such as Alan Bensky, *Wireless Positioning Technologies and Applications*, 2ed, 2016, Artech House, ISBN 1608079511.  This is a weighty book, you'll find the contents pages online at Google Books to see it covers GPS, Cellular Radio, RFID and many other things, including localisation by signal strength.
- Search online for "3d localization algorithm" and you'll find a great deal on the subject.

A fascinating use of positioning (but certainly off-topic for NE) is the following "reverse" use of GPS.  We know the position of the satellites and the times of the transmissions; if we know where the receiver is, we can calculate the actual transmission speed, which varies principally on the amount of water vapour in the air.  Thus we can find the water vapour in the line between the receiver and the various satellites.  Global networks of special GPS receivers (eg Suominet) are the basis for much current water vapour measurement.

- Bevis, M., S. Businger, T. A. Herring, C. Rocken, R. A. Anthes, and R.
  H.Ware (1992), "GPS meteorology–Remote-sensing of atmospheric
  water-vapor using the Global Positioning System", *J. Geophys.
  Res.*, 97(D14), 15, 787–15, 801

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can I ask one question to you? Should I set up at least three scanners when I want to distinguish the 2D directions? My target is pedestrian so 2D localization should be needed I thought (except Z-axis).

Comment: Yes, you'll need three, but usually more is better, it helps with the noise.  Frankly I wouldn't even try it by time-of-flight unless you have special sensors.  Signal strength method is practical, especially for slow-moving things like pedestrians.  Use SNMP to get the strengths from the access points or AP controller, then process it.  It's easier than you think to get something, and very much harder than you imagine to make it accurate.  Every constraint you have helps: can you map the space?  is it flat?  can you choose sensor locations?

Comment: I'll keep in mind that it's harder than I thought. I can map the space, it is flat and I can choose the sensor locations. The final goal is to minimize a number of Wi-Fi scanners when I want to get pedestrian trajectories in real commercial streets. I might set up all intersections by one scanner. However I thought I can reduce the number of scanners when I distinguish the directions. I will try to make this localization based on your advise (Signal). It was very helpful. If possible, could you give me more information?

Comment: When you have specific equipment, ask here about getting signal strengths via SNMP.  (Cisco command line is ` show dot11 associations` and `show dot11 associations MACADDR`, answer is eg `-41 dBm`).  Then read Bensky book chapter 10 or search `wifi signal strength positioning algorithm` where you will find many, eg "Improved Wifi Positioning Algorithm", Ma et al, 2015 https://doi.org/10.3390/s150921824 (full text online) which includes good sample data.  For help with applying the algorithms, you're probably better off asking with [gis] or [programming] or [stackoverflow].

Comment: Thanks. I have raspberry Pi and can get the RSSI. Thanks again. I hope that I can minimize the number of the scanners.